# How to listen to all bundle events?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I have already written an eclipse plugin that registers a [BundleListener](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleListener.html) to the [BundleContext](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html) in which it is [started](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator.html). The registered listener will log all [BundleEvents](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleEvent.html). I noticed that there are only events of type [STARTED](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleEvent.html#STARTED) logged.

I have registered the bundle to start at level 2 in the `config.ini` of eclipse with a default bundle start level of 4.

Is there any way that I am able to listen to events of type RESOLVED for example? Am I starting the bundle too late for receiving events of that type? Is there maybe more than one bundle context used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forcing ordering is in general a bad idea and worse in OSGi due to the dynamics. You can get something that looks like it has ordering with start levels but it is guaranteed to be very fragile and quickly becoming horribly complex. Since in general you need events to discover state I wonder what your use case is. In OSGi, finding the Bundle state is trivial. For applications that need the event for state discovery the BundleTracker provides a very nice API to discover bundles in a set of states. In my experience, the BundleTracker fits well for 99% of the BundleListener use cases.

If you're just logging, all Framework events are logged to the Log Service and the Log Service is usually started up very early. With a Log Reader Service you can get access to events that happened before you got started.

Comment: I know that it's bad practice. However I need to profile the startup of our eclipse, because that is very slow (mainly due to old boxes, but that's something that can't be changed quickly). Thanks for the tip with the BundleTracker and the LogService. That looks promising.

Comment: You are probably too late to see the RESOLVED events since Equinox will likely have already resolved all the bundles before the first bundle is started and can register a listener to see bundle events.

Comment: I guess you could see the RESOLVED events by writing a launcher and registering a listener with the framework before installing any bundles. But again... why??